# Clear Immediate Window from Code in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is there any way to clear the text that is written to the Immediate Window by `Debug.WriteLine` function from code-behind?

EDIT:

```
   public void ClearImmediateWindow()
   {
        EnvDTE.DTE refDTE;
        EnvDTE.Window currentActiveWindow = refDTE.ActiveWindow;
        refDTE.Windows.Item("{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}").Activate();
        refDTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll");
        refDTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll");
        currentActiveWindow.Activate();
   }
```

Comment: You mean like, remove all controls? or clear all texts/checks etc entered by a user?

Comment: Right-click in immediate window and *Clear All*?

Answer (score 2):

I've found this VB code:

```vb
Sub ClearImmediateWindow()
    Dim currentActiveWindow As Window = DTE.ActiveWindow
    DTE.Windows.Item("{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}").Activate() 'Immediate Window
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SelectAll")
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
    currentActiveWindow.Activate()
End Sub
```

on [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?393558-Clear-the-Immediate-Window-programmatically) website

[Link to msdn for DTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300825%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), google around for that I'm not familliar to the VB language. I'm sure you can find more information about DTE on google/msdn :)

Comment: try something like this.ActiveWindow

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have now, so we can see your progress? Including the errors you get ofcourse :)

Comment: Thanks, I can not figure how to solve the problem. I hope someone else can help there :)

Answer (score 0):

"Check" that this is unchecked in Visual Studio:

> Tools > Options > Debugging > "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window"

Comment: @Root If it's checked, it will redirect the text from the *Output* window to the *Immediate window*. Which I'm guessing you are experiencing.

Comment: If you want to clear the *Output* window, you can right click it and *Clear all*. If you don't want to see all messages, you can right click again and un-check the various messages or *Program output*.

Comment: I'm not quite following you. You want to clear the immediate window from code and you want to clear the output window from code. Then why are you using `Debug.WriteLine`? I see you already accepted an answer, so I guess it doesn't matter anymore.